# Trouble with vimrc file recognition with MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim, homebrew

I'm having difficulty getting MacVim (7.3-64) to recognize my `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` files since upgrading to OS X 10.7.3. Previous, I've simply symlinked my `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` using these commmands:

```
$ ln -s ~/.vim/vimrc /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-57/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/.vimrc 

$ ln -s ~/.vim/gvimrc /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-57/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/.gvimrc
```

However, when I currently symlink my rc files, I can not get MacVim to recognize them. I've installed MacVim via Homebrew. Does anyone have any suggests as to what the problem could be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `~/.vim/` folder (for colorschemes and scripts) and the `~/.vimrc` file (for custom settings and mappings) are guaranteed to work on every UNIX-like systems but neither of these are required for Vim (and MacVim) to work properly.

1. Start without symlinks or whatever : no `.vim` folder and no `.vimrc` or `.gvimrc` in your home folder. Does MacVim work? You are supposed to see a window with some introductory text, do you see that?
2. Quit MacVim and turn to the original `.(g)vimrc` files you want to use: where are they located? Where did you get them from? What is their content? Do you actually, really need them? Do their names actually start with a dot (do you see them or not in the Finder)? What is their encoding (in vim, `:set fileencoding?` and in the terminal, `$ file /path/to/original/.vimrc`)? Please, paste the content of the `.vimrc` file you want to use in your question.
3. If you are absolutely certain you *need* these files to work efficiently in Vim and assuming you actually have a custom `.vimrc` somewhere on your Mac, open Terminal.app and type this command (without the `$`):

   ```
   $ cp /path/to/original/.vimrc ~/.vimrc
   ```

   to *copy* your `.vimrc` to the canonical location.

   Now launch MacVim. What do you see? You are supposed to see a window with some introductory text, is that what you see?
4. If MacVim doesn't work correctly with your `~/.vimrc` you might want to comment its content, relaunch MacVim, uncomment a few lines and so on until you eventually find a bad setting.

Comment: Thank for very much for the help. I plan to answer your questions, but while I was following your instructions I noticed that I cannot find the default location of the `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` files in MacVim (7.3-64). Previous versions of MacVim installed them to `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-64/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/`

Comment: Here is the core of your problem. **You are not supposed to touch these files. Leave them where they are, don't even look at their content as it's totally useless for you.** When you need to keep some settings from session to session you'll put them in your own `~/.vimrc`. When you want to try a new plugin or colorscheme you'll put it in your own `~/vim/` folder. I repeat: **You are not supposed to touch these files. Leave them where they are, don't even look at their content as it's totally useless for you.**

Comment: I have a completely stock MacVim setup currently (I just installed it via Homebrew). Macvim did not install a .vimrc file into my home directory.

Comment: That's normal. It is not supposed to. If you want/need one you create one.

Comment: Where does MacVim read the `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` files from when first installed?

Comment: From `/path/to/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/[vimrc|gvimrc]` but again **it doesn't matter, knowing where those files are or having a look at their content is absolutely useless**. If you want/need a `.vimrc` you **must** create one yourself in `~` (right, IMO) or put someone else's there (wrong, IMO).

Comment: Yes, I know, there is always an old villager saying with a grave voice to the group of teenager that they shouldn't go near the lake/castle. But they always go…

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will look into this and try to stay away from the castle.

Answer (score 3):

Just put your `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` into your home directory, i.e. `~/` It's picked up there allright.

BTW, you don't need to link to the homebrew dir. Those rc files are default files which you can override with your local user files.

Comment: If I do as you suggest, I can launch the app, but I do not get a window or buffer. Also, I keep all my rc files in a separate directory under version control, so I'd like to keep these files in an alternative location than the home directory.

Comment: no problem with that. Create a `.vim` dir, put your `vimrc` files in there and hard link your `~/.vimrc` files to your `~/.vim/vimrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, this still doesn't work. Even if I put the rc files in the home directory MacVim is not picking them up?!

Comment: have you sourced your rc files again? Or restarted MacVim for that matter? Is MacVim picking up the right files at all? Check `:echo $MYVIMRC`to see what file is loaded.

Comment: If I place my `.vimrc` and `gvimrc` files in my home directory, MacVim will not open a new window. If I remove these files, MacVim will open a new window. Running `:echo $MYVIMRC` does nothing.